# How to trigger a core dump in php?

Tags: php, coredump

My web application occasionally - but very rarely - throws a particular exception. I don't know why it happens, and I haven't been able to reproduce it, or seen it occur anywhere except on my production server. So, I want to be able, when that particular exception happens, to dump the entire current state of php so I can trace through its execution and figure out what triggered it.

I can't use xdebug, because this is a production server, and xebug slows down the execution (which is already slow enough). So, how can I tell php to dump its current state, so I can examine it later?

The only thing I can think of, is to use `exec` to `kill` the current process, but that seems very messy, and it would be better in any case if I could dump the php state, rather than the apache state. I don't even know if that is possible...

Comment: If this is really an exception and not a crash, you could declare a global exception handler to collect the stack trace, etc.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Right, but then how do I get the rest of the state? i.e. the contents of memory, and the variables in scope higher up the stack?

Answer (score 0):

`debug_backtrace()` gives all args and functions requested so you can see its path and what called it.

You can save this to a file and review it piece by piece

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't give the contents of memory, and in particular it does not give the values of variables in scopes high up the stack trace. Any idea how to get them?

Comment: Why are the variables not passed down ? If they are class variables you will still have access, if not they shouldnt change the flow of the program